# Pasting Excel Range to Outlook Template

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro that is supposed to load an Outlook template, copy an Excel range and then paste it as an image to this template.

On my code, however, the image is pasted over the email template. As such, I end up with only the image overriding the whole email.

How can I only add the image to the Email body, as to have both the template and the image in it?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Update()

Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set otlNewMail = otlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\MyVBA\OutlookTemplate.oft")
With otlNewMail
vTemplateBody = otlNewMail.HTMLBody
vTemplateSubject = "Daily Update"
.Close 1
End With

'Creating the email from the template
Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set otlNewMail = otlApp.CreateItem(0)
With otlNewMail
.Display
.Bcc = vToList
.Subject = vTemplateSubject
.HTMLBody = vTemplateBody
End With

'Get Outlook's Word editor
otlNewMail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = otlNewMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'Defining the range to be pasted
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Table")
ws1.Activate
Range(ws1.Cells(1, 10), ws1.Cells(1, 15)).Copy

'To paste as picture
wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably re-think your concept and do it like this.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm